# Planet Orbit simulation using ODEINT in python. Four coupled first order ode. Code seems right but not plotting right

Tags: python

[The problem I'm trying to code in python is linked here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fA2jk.png)

I'm trying to program an orbit simulation between the Earth and the sun using four coupled ode with ODEINT as described in the problem linked above but no matter how I write it, it either gives an overtime error or just plots the wrong graphs.

Below is my current code:

```
from scipy.integrate import odeint
m=6*(10**24)
M=2*(10**30)
G=6.8*(10**(-11))
def orbit(f, t):
    x, y, vx, vy = f
    r=sqrt((x**2)+(y**2))
    v=sqrt((vx**2)+(vy**2))
    dx=vx
    dy=vy
    dfx=-G*m*x/(r**3)
    dfy=-G*m*y/(r**3)
    dFdt = [dx, dy, dfx, dfy]
    return dFdt
t=np.linspace(0,3.2*(10**7))
x0=0
y0=1.5*(10**11)
vx0=3*(10**4)
vy0=0
f = odeint(orbit,(x0,y0, vx0, vy0),t)
plt.plot(t,f[:, 0])
#plt.plot(t, f[:,1])
plt.figure()
plt.plot(f[:,1],f[:,0])
plt.show()
```

I've let out all the imports and stuff so this is just the main body of the code. But I've taken out the mass of the Sun which is big M as that cancels out in the math. Even if I add M back in, there's an error as values become too large. Other than that it looks like it should work but here are my plots.

Here's the current plot of just the x values:

[image: Plot X]

The current phase plot y vs x:

[image: Phase Plot y vs x]

Both plots look linear when it shouldn't and I'm not sure why.

I even tried separating the four ode into two ODEINT functions and it just prints out essentially the same plots.

I've stared at the code for 2 hours trying to figure out what's wrong but I honestly can't tell except maybe my initial values aren't optimal. But the values were given to me by the problem itself. I'm absolutely stuck and don't know how to move forward from here.

Comment: Recognize that the `orbit` function should, given a state `X`, return the time-derivative i.e. `X'`. Knowing that `X = [x, y, vx, vy]`, `X'` is `[vx, vy, ax, ay]` (the last two elements are the _accelerations_ of the Earth. Your equation for the Earth's acceleration should contain the _sun's_ mass, not the Earth's.

Comment: Fix that typo and your code works fine: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VM1HP.png

Comment: @pho I'm not following, what exactly am I fixing in my code? Just switching the masses?

Comment: Yes. `dfx=-G*M*x/(r**3)`. same change for `dfy`

Comment: @pho switching the masses seems to have done the trick! I guess I got my variables mixed up when doing the math. Thanks!